# How to display API data using fetch on Dialogflow GUI

Tags: fetch-api, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to display data from OMDB API on Dialogflow GUI but it's not happening. Data is being displayed fine on Google Cloud Console.

```
function infoHandler(agent){
    let movieName = agent.parameters.movie;
    agent.add(`The information for ${movieName} is as follow`);
    fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=e255decd%20&s='+ movieName)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then((json) => {
        let id = json.Search[0].imdbID;
        fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=e255decd%20&i=' + id)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then((json) => {
                agent.add(json.Title + json.Plot + json.imdbRatinng);
          return;
            }).catch((ex) => {
                console.log(ex);
            });
    })
    .catch((e) => {console.log(e);});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `fetch()` causes an asynchronous operation. However, there is nothing that indicates to the Dialogflow handler dispatcher that it is asynchronous and that it should wait for it to complete before sending back a reply. To do that, you'd need to return a Promise.

Fortunately the then/catch chain that you have that are built off the `fetch()` return a Promise. So all you need to do is return the Promise that they have. This is as simple, in your case, by placing a `return` before the `fetch()` call. So it would look something like this:

```
    return fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=e255decd%20&s='+ movieName)
      // Other lines remain the same
```